# Number pipe gives string value instead of number

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pipe

I have the following lines of code. It's basically an input field in my html. I am adding a number pipe to it since it's a currency field. By default it's empty, when the user adds value to it, it should autoformat it as currency. But am getting a rare issue here.

> vendor.dll.js:55094 EXCEPTION: Invalid argument '8,888.038' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'

HTML:

```
<div class="form-input">
                    <cust-input
                            [ngModel]="Amnt | number:'.2-2'"
                            (ngModelChange)="Amnt=$event"
                            type="tel"
                            (keyup)="getAmount(RqstdAmnt)"
                            [ngClass]="{'inValid-requested-amount-class': AmountValid===false}"
                            placeholder="{{'amount_placeHolder' | translate}}">
                    </cust-input>
                </div>
```

TS:

```
RqstdAmnt:number;
getRequestedAmount(amount:number) {
        if (amount > somevalue) {
             console.log('value higher');
        } else {
             console.log('value lower');
        }
    }
```

May I know what's the right way to do it? We can have another way, when user clicks on the input field no pipe, when the mouseout add the currency pipe. I am not sure how to do that. Can you guys guide me how can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you declare the field Amnt in your component?

Comment: yes. thats the one i put on top of my function

Answer (score 0):

Using a pipe with `ngModel` is not the best idea, as when user is typing the pipe will run at every keystroke. I have implemented similar scenario using `blur` and `focus`. `.00` gets added and removed depending on user input and doesn't interfere with the interaction.

Here's the code if you want to use it in yours:

html:

```
<md-input-container class="example-full-width">
    <input mdInput placeholder="Amount" 
           type="number" 
           [(ngModel)]="amount" 
           formControlName="amount" 
           (blur)="format(amount)" 
           (focus)="remove(amount)">
  </md-input-container>
```

ts:

```
format(amt){
    // console.log(amt % 1 == 0);
    if(amt % 1 == 0){
      amt = amt + '.00';
      this.amount = amt;
    }
  }

  remove(amt){
    // console.log(amt % 1 == 0);
    if(amt % 1 == 0){
      this.amount = amt * 1;;
    }
  }

  submit(form){
    alert(JSON.stringify(form));
  }
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mrEcN7?p=preview)